# Allow frameset cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, http, xss

I have two servers `server1.contoso.com` and `server2.contoso.com` and have to display content of both servers in two frames of the same frameset:

```
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="http://server1.contoso.com/invoices/index.html?open">
  <frame src="http://server2.contoso.com/invoices_new/index.html">
</frameset>
```

Both servers host an invoice system each. These systems cannot be put on a single server, and neither server may reverse-proxy the other.

Now I want the ExtJS grid in both frames to scroll synchronously. But I can't access the frames' content and hook into their `scroll` events due to cross-site scripting restrictions.

How can I circumvent this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the `domain` property? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6046650/2101267

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy