# Hide dynamic element on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, colorbox

I have a page which uses colorbox to load an iframe(proprietary information).

I need to hide an element in the iframe(takes a few seconds to load) with a specific class.

I tried this with no success. The console messages are not hit. One they are hit, I can then hide them using jQuery css.

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    $(".className").ready(function () {
        console.log("className on class ready");
        $(".className").css("display", "none");
    });

    $(document).on("ready", ".className", function () {
        console.log("className on document ready");
        $(".className").css("display", "none");
    });

});
```

Colorbox init:

```
function ShowColorbox(fileId) {

    'use strict';

    var colorboxUrl = getColorBoxUrl();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: colorboxUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (previewLink) {
            $.colorbox({ href: previewLink, iframe: true, width: "90%", height: "90%" });

        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("failed");
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });

}
```

Plain CSS approach(did not work either):

```
<style>
        .className .UITextTranformUpperCase {
            display: none;
        } 
    </style>
```

Comment: Did you try using plain CSS?

Comment: Is the page in the current domain? If no then you can't target elements inside `iframe` [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: The page is in the same domain but different subdomain

Comment: Then it is possible, but you have to target the iframe contents as an object. I have the code somewhere I will post it. Does the iframe have an id or class?

Comment: have you tried adding the js display none to a callback for when the popup has opened? `onComplete: $(".className").css("display", "none");`

Comment: Yes the iframe has a fixed class but dynamic id

Comment: Could you add the code of your colorbox initialization in your post ?

Comment: @Aaron I tried using onOpen, onLoad, onComplete but then the iframe does not complete loading and display the element with className by then

Answer (score 0):

Your colorbox uses a dynamic url for content. You have to be sure that the content is loaded before finding elements.

You just have to set the [`fastIframe`](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/#setting-fastiframe) property to `false` and add an `onComplete` handler and it should work :

```
$.colorbox({ 
    href: previewLink, 
    iframe: true, 
    width: "90%", 
    height: "90%",
    fastIframe: false,
    onComplete : function() {
        $('#cboxIframe').contents().find('.className').hide();
    }
});
```

Please just verify that your colorbox iframe has the id `cboxIframe`. If not, update the iframe selector

Comment: This event triggered much later than without the fastIframe option. However the iframe was still not completed loaded. The previewLink is a link to a Office Web App preview link which is processed by an Office Web App service to show a preview

Comment: I changed the colorbox frame to use the class as the id is dynamic. Now I have a "Access is denied". This must be a cross sub-domain issue!

Comment: Yes it seems to be a cross domain issue : [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Two sub domains from a domain are two different hosts for the browser...

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have done it in the past:

```
$('iframe.yourclass').load(function(){
    $iframe = $('iframe.yourclass').contents();
    $iframe.find('.class-selector').css('display','none');
});
```

However if the iframe is on the same domain, can you not write simple css to target the element. Or maybe you do not have access to the css?

Comment: subdomain1.domain.com - I have access to this. I wrote simple CSS here. The iframe which is loaded is from subdomain2.domain.com to which I do not have access.

Comment: I wasn't sure about subdomains, but there seems to be more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046558/cross-sub-domain-iframes-and-javascript