# XXS on same domain not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to search through an iFrame from a separate website.

One is my.website.com

Other is website.com

website.com is searching for text located in the iframe from my.website.com but its getting blocked by jquery. Is this blocked because its a different website? They are both the same domain.

I was looking at CORS headers to see if there was a way to allow jquery to search the text... Its dumb that its blocking even searching, its not manipulating anything.

Found this solution here: [Cross sub domain iframes and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046558/cross-sub-domain-iframes-and-javascript)

How do I do this though. Where do I add the default.domain?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [Cross sub domain iframes and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046558/cross-sub-domain-iframes-and-javascript)

Comment: That is my problem.. How do I add a document.domain to the webpage?

Comment: sub domain isn't same domain. The more correct term to use though is *same origin*, because you can certainly have same domain cases that don't work for the same reason, because they don't have the same port and/or protocol.

Answer (score -1):

You can access every variable of the parent window `website.com` in your case throught the `window.parent` object.
Maybe you can try setting some variables of website.com with the following function inside my.website.com

```
document.onload = function () {
    if (window !== window.top && window.parent !== window) {
        // we're probably inside an iframe
        window.parent.someVariable = 'Some value!';
    }
};
```

And then you can call `someVariable` inside website.com

> A reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.
>
> If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference
>   to itself.
>
> When a window is loaded in an , , or , its
>   parent is the window with the element embedding the window.
>
> Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent